# Flash Links Don't Work Cross Domain

Tags: flash, swfobject

I searched for an answer, but I can't find one.

I have a flash accordion embedded using SWFObject.  The SWF and related XML file are hosted on one domain.  I have about 10 sites embedding this SWF from it's hosted location, both the SWF and the XML.  The accordion links to various pages of my domains.  The domain in which the SWF and XML file are hosted, the links work as expected.  The other domains that the SWF is not hosted on, the links do not work at all.  I verified it's a cross domain issue by placing the SWF and XML files locally on each domain and they worked, but this is not how I want it setup.  I attempted to use crossdomain.xml and allow access from all hosts but that didn't work either.  What else can I try?

Comment: What are the domains involved (you can use fake names like a.com, sub.b.com, etc. if necessary), and what crossdomain.xml file did you try?

Comment: They are all like domain.com, no subdomains involved.

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Answer (score 0):

Add to your fla file

```
System.security.allowDomain("*");
```

This will enable loading add access from any domain.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but this is a purchased flash file.  I have the FLA, I think, but it's been a while so I gotta make sure I still have it first.